# Using GeoJSON in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib

I have been trying the whole evening to produce a map using a given link. However, I could not figure out what the problem was.
I am using python notebook and would like to produce the map of San Francisco using GeoJSON.

I have been given the following link: https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson and then I tried to read it into my machine using

`!wget --quiet https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson -o sanfran_geojson.json` but I was not successful.
Further I am going to use the following:
`sanfran_geo = r'sanfran_geojson` # geojson file

## create a plain world map

`sanfran_map = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=12, tiles='Mapbox Bright')`
`sanfran_map`

## generate choropleth

````
    geo_data=sanfran_geo,
    data=sa1,
    columns=['Neighborhood', 'Count'],
    key_on='feature.properties.name',
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Immigration to Canada'
)```
# where sa1 is a dataframe contains to columns'Neighborhood' in San Fran. and 'Count' the number of crimes of each neighborhood.
# display map
```sanfran_map```

Any help would be very appreciated.
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your main problem is related to the fact that you're running your jupyter notebook in Windows and `wget` utility is not available in your system.

The most direct way to workaround without actually installing [wget for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) is using a Python http client, for example, `urlib.request`.

I've noted by the legend of your choropleth map that you're using another dataset (Canada Immigration), so make sure you change pandas `Dataframe` and the column names you provide in the `data` and `columns` parameters of your choropleth map.

Assuming you're using **python 3.x**:

```
!pip install folium

import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import folium

#Download San FranciscoCrime DataSet

sf_crime = pd.read_csv('https://cocl.us/sanfran_crime_dataset')
sf_crime.drop(['IncidntNum', 'Category', 'Descript', 'DayOfWeek', 'Date', 'Time', 'Resolution', 'Address', 'X', 'Y', 'Location', 'PdId'], axis=1, inplace=True)
by_zone = sf_crime.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).reset_index()
by_zone.rename(columns={'index':'Neighborhood', 'PdDistrict':'Count'}, inplace=True)

# Download San Francisco district polygon GeoJSON

url = 'https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'sf_neighborhoods.json')
sf_zones = r'sf_neighborhoods.json'


# Define San Francisco Center point
sf_lat = 37.77
sf_lon = -122.42

#Create Folium Map
sf_crime_map = folium.Map(location=[sf_lat, sf_lon], 
                         zoom_start=12, 
                         tiles='Mapbox Bright')

#Create choropleth map with neighborhood polygon colored with crime metric
sf_crime_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=sf_zones,
    data=by_zone,
    columns=['Neighborhood', 'Count'],
    key_on='feature.properties.DISTRICT',
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='San Fransisco Crime by Neighborhood'
)

#Plot map
sf_crime_map
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you a lot. Now I know what the problem was.